# Rounding down to nearest whole number when integer has multiple periods

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I am collecting browser versions, so if someone is using Chrome a value could be "77.0.3865.75"

How do I round this value down to nearest whole number (floor)? Having multiple periods seems to break built in math functions.

Comment: Version strings are not numbers. Just process it as a string, removing everything after the first `.`

Comment: `number.split('.')[0]`

Comment: `Having multiple periods seems to break built in math functions.` Why are you performing math on a version string in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by `nearest whole number` from something like "77.0.3865.75"? If you mean `77` then `number.split('.')[0]` as pointed by Barmar is what you need. If not, can you please explain what you want to achieve exactly and also share the code of what you tried? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Barmar's solution worked perfectly.